# administrative password doesn't work

Tags: password

I'm trying to install the Virtual Box extentions to add USB 2.0 functionality. While I install, a box pops up and asks for the administrative password.  When I enter the password, it tells me it was incorrect and I can't install.

I only have Ubuntu installed on my laptop, and I'm the only user, so the admin password is **my** password.

Any help, or is this just a bug? I've got 13.04 btw.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password?rq=1

Comment: Try to do this:

1. Open a terminal.

2. Input: sudo passwd

3. Write your user password.

4. Write the same password.

5. Write the same password.

6. Try to install the extension again and write the user password.

Comment: David, totally worked! Thanks for the help!  I can't seem to mark this as solved since these are comments though.

Comment: Added as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Input: `sudo passwd`
3. Write your user password.
4. Write the same password.
5. Write the same password.
6. Try to install the extension again and write the user password.